# How to select an item from list and store it on the state React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Im having hard time to resolve this logic, I hope somebody can help. When the address 2 is pressed I want to get that value and replace the Address 1 with it. How can I select the item and store it on the state or replace the Address 1 with it??? Below is my code:

```
 const [collapse, setCollapse] = useState(false);
```

```
 <Collapse
          style={styles.locationContainer}
          isCollapsed={collapse}
          onToggle={(isCollapsed) => setCollapse(isCollapsed)}
        >
          <CollapseHeader>
            <View onPress={() => setCollapse(!collapse)}>
              <Text style={styles.title}>Choose location</Text>
              <View style={styles.friendsContainer}>
                <View style={styles.itemsContainerLocation}>
                  <Text style={styles.subTitle}>Address 1</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.default}>(default)</Text>
                </View>
                {collapse ? (
                  <Ionicons name="ios-arrow-up" size={24} color="black" />
                ) : (
                  <Ionicons name="ios-arrow-down" size={20} color="black" />
                )}
              </View>
            </View>
          </CollapseHeader>
          <CollapseBody>
            <View style={styles.adressesContainer}>
              <TouchableOpacity>
                <Text style={styles.adressesName}>Address 2</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.adressesContainer}>
              <TouchableOpacity>
                <Text style={styles.adressesName}>Address 3</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.adressesContainer}>
              <TouchableOpacity>
                <Text style={styles.adressesName}>Address 4</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </CollapseBody>
        </Collapse>
```

Comment: There's only jsx in the code, where's the state logic and handlers?

Comment: I dont know how to implement the logic, can you help me? Im new to react native

Comment: At least you could try something and if it does not work then we could help. To be honest this could be very easy if you learn and implement it yourself :)

Comment: Thank you, Im trying but the I think the library dosent support onPress at all

Answer (score 3):

See [react tutorial on state and lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class).

Something similar to

```js
const addresses = ['Address1', 'Address2', ...];

const [selectedAddressIndex, setSelectedAddressIndex] = useState(0);

// render selected address
<>
  <Text>{addresses[selectedAddressIndex]}</Text>
</>

// render each selectable address inside a TouchableOpacity
<>
  {
    addresses.map((address, index) => (
      <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={() => setSelectedAddressIndex(index)}>
        <Text>{address}</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity/>
    ))
  }
</>
```

should work for you.

`map` is a powerful array method in js that allows you to build identical components for elements in an array.

`onPress` in `TouchableOpacity` is the prop that accepts a callback function, whereby the callback function `() => setSelectedAddressIndex(index)` is called when an `onPress` event is fired.

Additionally, there is a new [Pressable](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable) component that react-native recommends, replacing `TouchableOpacity`.